# Android 2.2 doesnt work on new

Tags: android, eclipse

The Android 2.2 doesn't "Create Activity", I've been trying, no use. I checked the internet and it didn't work!

[image]

It used to work at the end of last year when I downloaded the two requirements, but now it doesn't.

Just in case, here is the SDK Manager

[image]

Comment: Make sure you installed the right software (*Help > Install New Software*) as *http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/* with *Developer Tools* checked.

Comment: Fllo: it gives more "Developer Tools" and "NDK Plugin" like before, when I check them, there will be nothing highlighted (no back, next not even the finish) it tells me "All items are installed"

Comment: Bob Malooga: it tells me "No updates were found".

Comment: Here is the "Window > Preferences" http://oi59.tinypic.com/zogoqa.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot build a project with Eclipse at least you don't use the higher library. You can see the error message which says:

> **This template requires a build target API version of at least 14**, and the current version is 8.

[image: API 8 new project (Compile with API 8)]

To create a new project with `Google API 8`, you should create all the stuff manually (by unchecking *Create Activity* from the above screenshot):

1. create the `package` (Click right on *src* folder > New > Package)
2. create the `Activity` (Click right on *package* created > New > Class)
3. create the `layout` which will be used inside the activity
4. modify the `AndroidManifest.xml` to add the activities

Comment: Will I be working with "Android 2.2"? Because http://oi61.tinypic.com/qnv7dz.jpg and http://oi59.tinypic.com/qo989w.jpg

Comment: Hum.. Indeed @Sa77a, I don't think that's a good practice: *Using 1.7 requires compiling with Android 4.4 (KitKat); currently using API 8*. I got this error when I changed manually the API Google Services. Why don't you uncheck *Create Activity* and build it by yourself? It might be easier.

Comment: I always uncheck but worried :) I'll set it unchecked now because you said so! it has lots of errors and I'll post whenever Im stuck at one .. Thank you very much Fllo :)

Comment: I updated my answer @Sa77a. You will not have any error if you uncheck the *Create Activity* parameter. You will just have to build all the stuff manually (which are mentioned in my answer above). HTH